# Django ORM making query

Tags: sql, django-orm, postgresql-9.6

I'm new to `django` and `SQL` too.
I need to make a list of supplier's products that have cheaper counterparts, then one that logged in (with the same `product_id`) available from other suppliers
Requirements: `Django=2.2 PostgreSQL=9.6`
Let me know how to do this by `django-ORM`, and what code should be by using just SQL-language
Here is the model.

```
Models.py
class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField('product name', max_length=50)
    product = models.CharField('vendor code', default=None, max_length=50, unique=True)

class Supplier(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField('Supplier name', default='', max_length=50)

Class SupplierProduct(models.Model): 
    supplier = models.ForeignKey(Supplier, default=None, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, default=None, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    product_price = models.DecimalField('Price', default=None, max_digits=11, decimal_places=2)
    availability = models.BooleanField(default=False)

Views.py
def foo(request):
    user = request.user
```

Comment: Thanks to everyone. My question has changed. I've solved it in SQL. And how it should be in ORM ? SELECT *
FROM (
    (
    SELECT * FROM SupplierProduct a
    WHERE a.supplier_id = 2
    ) AS my JOIN (
    SELECT * FROM SupplierProduct b
    WHERE b.supplier_id <> 2
    ) AS others ON my.product_id = others.product_id
  )
WHERE 
  my.product_price > others.product_price
  AND  my.availability = true
  AND  others.availability = true

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SupplierProduct.objects.annotate(
    has_cheaper=Exists(SupplierProduct.objects.filter(
        Q(supplier__name=user),
        ~Q(supplier_id=OuterRef('supplier_id')),
        product_id=OuterRef('product_id'),
        product_price__gt = OuterRef('product_price')
        )
    )
).filter(availability=True, has_cheaper=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of an [**`Exists`** subquery [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/expressions/#exists-subqueries):

```
from django.db.models import Exists, OuterRef, Q

SupplierProduct.objects.filter(
    Exists(SupplierProduct.objects.filter(
        ~Q(supplier_id=OuterRef('supplier_id')),
        product_id=OuterRef('product_id'),
        product_price__lt=OuterRef('product_price')
    ))
)
```

We thus retain `SupplierProduct`s for which there exists a `SupplierProduct` with a different `supplier`, the same `product_id`, and a lower price.

Prior to [django-3.0](/questions/tagged/django-3.0), you first annotate, and then filter:

```
Django-2.2 and older

from django.db.models import Exists, OuterRef, Q

SupplierProduct.objects.annotate(
    has_cheaper=Exists(SupplierProduct.objects.filter(
        ~Q(supplier_id=OuterRef('supplier_id')),
        product_id=OuterRef('product_id'),
        product_price__lt=OuterRef('product_price')
    ))
).filter(has_cheaper=True)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer !!! But it doesn't works on django 2.2, it works on django>=3.

Comment: @Rash-77: then you first need to annotate, see edit.